# Custom heading with tex4ht

Tags: header-footer, tex4ht

tex4ht generates a page head and foot with navigation elements, such as `[next] [tail] [up]` with hyperlinks.

Now I would like to change that appearance to have the page heading left and right of the title:

```
[prev] My second section [next]
```

instead of

```
[prev] [next]

My second section
```

and (challange!) in the foot:

```
[prev] My first section <-            -> My third section [next]
```

where `My first section` is the name of the previos section and similar with `My third section`

Comment: I found an obscure reference to `\Configure{crosslinks}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}` (eight parameters!) which seems to configure the way the navigation links behave. Unfortunately I never got `tex4ht` to work, so I can't test it. `:(`

Answer (score 3):

Your first question is not so hard. Just create dummy `sty` file, `testcrosslink.sty` for example, `testcrosslink.4ht` and put `\usepackage{testcrosslink}` to your document preamble.

Content of `testcrosslink.4ht`:

```
\def\my:nextlink{%
\ifx\nextCut\empty\relax\else[\Link[\nextCut]{}{}Next\EndLink]\fi
}
\def\my:prevlink{%
\ifx\prevCut\empty\relax\else[\Link[\prevCut]{}{}Prev\EndLink]\fi
}

\Configure{section}{\empty}{\empty}{\HCode{<h3>}\my:prevlink}{\my:nextlink\HCode{</h3>}}
\Configure{crosslinks+}{}{}{\empty}{\empty}
```

This configuration makes top crosslinks empty and redefines section to include links to previous and next file.

To change bottom crosslinks, you can try this:

```
\Configure{crosslinks}{}{}{ -> \macrofornexttitle [next]}{[prev] \macroforprevtitle <- }{}{}{}{}
\Configure{crosslinks*}{prev}{next}{}
```

For more information about various configuration options for crosslinks etc., see the CVR's [blog](http://www.cvr.cc/tex/tex4ht/configure/)

Problem is, I don't know how to automatically retrieve contents of prev and next sections, so how to define macros `\macrofornexttitle` and `\macroforprevtitle` must answer someone else. Maybe it could be done using `nameref` or `zref` and automatically generated labels, but what I have tried failed.